# Firefox timeout while waiting for download dialog

Tags: firefox, download, timeout

What is the key in about:config (given the information I'm looking for is there) to look for if I have a browser timeout issue while waiting for the download dialog box?

Comment: Why downvoting this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the page about all the [about:config entries](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries)

Comment: +1 , Why this is downvoted, have a look at network.http.connect.timeout property --> http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.connect.timeout

Comment: I think it's been downvoted cause someone was too lazy to search needed information by following the link. Anyway thank you UK.

Comment: Thank you both, I found that the property i needed was network.http.keep-alive.timeout